# Prometheus Alertmanager config

Tags: prometheus, prometheus-alertmanager

I have below config to send email alerts from my prometheus based on matching label.

```
global:
  smtp_from: 'monitor@a.com'
  smtp_smarthost: '1.1.1.1:25'
  smtp_require_tls: false
templates:
- '/etc/alertmanager/default.tmpl'
route:
  receiver: 'default-receiver'
  group_by: [cluster, severity]
  group_wait: 10s
  group_interval: 5m
  repeat_interval: 1h
inhibit_rules:
- source_match:
    severity: critical
  target_match:
    severity: warning
  routes:
  - receiver: 'default-receiver'
  email_configs:
  - to: "b@a.com,h@a.com,c@a.com,d@a.com"
    send_resolved: true
  - receiver: 'datalake-receiver'
  email_configs:
  - to: "b@a.com,h@a.com,e@a.com"
    match_re:
      kubernetes_namespace: datalake-aws-ec2|datalake-piaas-instances
    send_resolved: true
  - receiver: 'bundling-receiver'
  email_configs:
  - to: "b@a.com,h@a.com,f@a.com,g@a.com"
    match_re:
      kubernetes_namespace: bundling-prod-axa-sg|rabbitmq
    send_resolved: true
```

I deployed this config but my container is not coming up. Can someone help me verify the syntax and suggest what's wrong in above config. I tried all possible combination but no luck.
Thanks in Advance.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There're a lot of issues related to YAML identation and Alertmanager configuration format. The following configuration seems to be working as expected:

```
global:
  smtp_from: 'monitor@a.com'
  smtp_smarthost: '1.1.1.1:25'
  smtp_require_tls: false

templates:
- '/etc/alertmanager/default.tmpl'

route:
  receiver: 'default-receiver'
  group_by: [cluster, severity]
  group_wait: 10s
  group_interval: 5m
  repeat_interval: 1h

  routes:
    - receiver: 'datalake-receiver'
      match_re:
        kubernetes_namespace: 'datalake-aws-ec2|datalake-piaas-instances'
    - receiver: 'bundling-receiver'
      match_re:
        kubernetes_namespace: 'bundling-prod-axa-sg|rabbitmq'

receivers:
  - name: 'default-receiver'
    email_configs:
      - to: 'b@a.com'
        send_resolved: true
      - to: 'h@a.com'
        send_resolved: true

  - name: 'datalake-receiver'
    email_configs:
      - to: 'b@a.com'
        send_resolved: true
      - to: 'h@a.com'
        send_resolved: true

  - name: 'bundling-receiver'
    email_configs:
      - to: 'b@a.com'
        send_resolved: true
      - to: 'h@a.com'
        send_resolved: true

inhibit_rules:
  - source_match:
      severity: critical
    target_match:
      severity: warning
```

Take a look at the [Routing tree editor](https://www.prometheus.io/webtools/alerting/routing-tree-editor/). It's good to test the Alertmanager configuration.

Comment: Thanks Marcelo for the help. This config works but the alerts are going to only first email.
Rest are ignored and not receiving.

Comment: I double-checked the email_configs syntax and it's correct. Check if you used the correct indentation and use the "routing tree editor" to see if it's correct (when you put your mouse over the receiver name in the tree, it shows the receivers ).